# My program stopped working because a p roblem has been detected?

Tags: c++, string

I tried looking at the other problems people were having that were along this line but i couldn't relate them to my program. This is probably very simple but I rarely if ever do anything C++ related so I am very confused. I try and run my program which and it works up until the point were I try to use "std::cout" to display the reversed name. The program runs for a bit in the command window but eventually a window's window pops up proclaiming there was a problem and that it will end the program. I have tried to break everything down so that it is simple as it can be yet I cannot for the life of me find what's wrong. Could anyone help? I apologize for anything I have done wrong in advance and apologies for bypassing the 'problem' title filter. Cheers!

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string.h>


std::string firstName;
std::string lastName;
std::string fullname;
std::string reverseName;
int x;
int Simplifier;
int willThisWork;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Welcome to this random program that serves \n";
    std::cout << "           NO PURPOSE!                     \n";
    std::cout << "That being said, what is your first name? : ";
    std::cin >> firstName;
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Okay... Now what is your last name? : ";
    std::cin >> lastName;
    std::cin.ignore();

    fullname = firstName + " " + lastName;
    std::cout << "Your full name is : " << fullname;

    nameLength = fullname.length();
    for(x = 0; x <= nameLength; x++)
    {
        Simplifier = nameLength - x;
        reverseName[x] = fullname[Simplifier];
    }
    std::cout << "Reversed name : " << reverseName;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have to go so the short answer. What I think is that `reverseName` has no space allocated and you're trying to change it. Try doing this: `reverseName += fullname[Simplifier];`

Comment: You have to append each letter and += overload does that (I think).

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  You need to include `string` and declare `nameLength`.  Once you've done that, try a debugger.

Comment: `nameLength` is an `int` and needs a type declaration. Other than that, this program compiles and runs fine for me (no "problem detected"). Also, should you `#include<string>` and not `#include<string.h>`

Comment: @RetiredNinja, my code does compile for me... How else would I run it and have windows popping up?

Comment: Is this under Turbo c++?

Comment: @TonyD I am using Code::Blocks 13.12. I am unsure what the exact compiler is.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the problem everyone. I am sorry for using up your time, have a fantastic day! (or night)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include `<string>` (the C++ header) instead of `<string.h>` (the C header).

`nameLength` is undeclared – has to be `int nameLength`.

Lastly,

```
Simplifier = nameLength - x;
reverseName[x] = fullname[Simplifier];
```

tries for `x==0` to access the one past the last element of `fullname`. Remember, indices go from `0` to `N-1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array/vector/string.

*Edit:* And you have to adjust the `for` loop: `x < nameLength` instead of `x <= nameLength`.

`reverseName` is an empty string, but you try to access its elements with `reverseName[x]`. Use `reverseName.push_back()` or `reverseName +=` instead.

Maybe add the odd `\n` to format your output.

Comment: I didn't really think of that.. Tried running again with reverseName[x] = fullname[Simplifier - 1]; and it works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: It actually shouldn't, unless you initialized `reverseName` or used one of the two methods I mentioned.